# Subset a list based on the contents in a vector

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a vector of dates called In_Period. I use this vector to subset a range of years from a list of matrices. However, when I subset, an $NA is introduced as the first element of the list. This is because the list of matrices may not have the year name as an element.

```
data_out[as.character(In_Period)]
>
$<NA>
NULL

$`1997`
     j
i     Aaa Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  Aaa   5  0  3   0  0  0   0
  Aa    5 26  4   2  0  0   0
  A     1 18 14   5  0  0   0
  Baa   0  4 16   8  5  0   2
  Ba    0  1  3  12  4  1   0
  B     0  1  0   1  3  2   0
  Caa   0  0  0   0  1  0   0
```

How do I correctly subset the named elements in the list using the vector of names?

The vector containing the dates:

```
In_Period <- c(1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
```

This is the list of matrices that are named by the date:

```
list(`1997` = structure(c(5L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 
18L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 16L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 
8L, 12L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", 
    "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `1998` = structure(c(6L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 12L, 
26L, 9L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `1999` = structure(c(6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 17L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2000` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 
17L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
10L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 3L, 2L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", 
"Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", 
"Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2001` = structure(c(1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 20L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 14L, 11L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2002` = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
15L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2003` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2004` = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 17L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
14L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2005` = structure(c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 16L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 6L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2006` = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 
21L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 15L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 
8L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2007` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2008` = structure(c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 8L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 14L, 
10L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2009` = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2010` = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 31L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 
14L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2011` = structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2012` = structure(c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
17L, 15L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 14L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)), `2013` = structure(c(0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 19L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 21L, 18L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)), `2014` = structure(c(0L, 
4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 38L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 12L, 
21L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", 
"A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ 
    i + j, data = .)))
```

Comment: Your `dput` fails in the last line `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : object '.' not found`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do alphabetical indexing.

```
 Name_of_list[ as.character(In_period] )
```

Just using the index without coercing to numeric would fail. I suppose you could also have tried to match against names() of the list. But that would seem a bit baroque.

If you want to avoid the NAs then use logical indexing

```
 data_out[ names(data_out) %in% as.character( In_Period) ]
```

Comment: It results in the first named element being $NA. I've updated my post to show what's happening.

Comment: Your example was created in an environment where there were values for `n`, `j`, `i` and the object named `.` (dot). This was probably done with some "tidyverse" function. The example cannot be used by any of us since it cannot access those values. I've made my best guess as to a solution, but it remains a guess in the absence of a [MCVE].